# VBA - find and replace a value with another value, if initial value is smaller than target value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm Robert, I am new to VBA and I have the following task to perform:
I have a series of numbers in 2 rows. If the number in the upper row is smaller than 1.3 than it should replace the corresponding value in lower row.

The numbers should be compared and replaced if necessary two by two, meaning the value in the upper row should replace the valuen in the lower row if upper value is smaller than 1.3.

If not, leave the value in the lower row as it is and move forward.

I have to write a code in VBA that will do this check-up automatically.

Have you ever seen/written such a code in VBA?

Thank you very much for the time!

This is what I did so far:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


For i = 1 To 12

If Cells(60, 8 + i) < 1.3 Then
Cells(60, 8 + i).Select
Selection.Copy
Cells(61, 8 + i).Select
Selection.PasteSpecialext Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

If Cells(60, 8 + i) > 1.3 Then
For j = 1 To 10
Cells(60, 8 + i).Select
Selection.Copy
Cells(61, 8 + i).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    If Cells(60, 8 + i) < 1.3 Then
    Cells(60, 8 + i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Cells(61, 8 + i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Next i

    If Cells(60, 8 + i) = Cells(61, 8 + i) Then Next i

    Else

    Cells(60, 8 + i).Select

Selection.Copy
Cells(61, 8 + i).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    If Cells(60, 8 + i) < 1.3 Then
    Cells(60, 8 + i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Cells(61, 8 + i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Next j

Next i

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Any efforts?

Comment: Yes, I can give you the excel file if you wish to see the code! Thanks!

Comment: You should include your current try in your question. Also watch http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: OK, I will post what I did so far, thank you for the advice!

Comment: I uploaded my code but please do not forget that I am very new to VBA!

Comment: What isn't working with your current code?

Comment: It gives me that "Next without For" error ... As I am new to VBA and even though I've googled it, I could not find a specific enaswer. Another problem is that I really do not know if what I did so far or parts of it is correct or not!

Comment: You're running `Next i` whilst still in the nested `For j =` loop. You can't do that. Remove the first and second `Next i`, leaving only the last instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** to meet OP's further specifications

may be you wanted something like follows:

```
Sub main()
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A1:D1") '<~~ change "Feuil1" as per your actual sheet name
    If cell.Value > 1.3 Then cell.Offset(1).Value = cell.Value
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It is pretty close to what I had in mind!

Comment: well it exactly fulfills the requirement that _"the value in the upper row should replace the value in the lower row if upper value is smaller than 1.3"_ as you wrote in your question. did you _have in mind_ something different then what you wrote'?

Comment: Yes, I worked a little on what you kindly gave me but now I Have a problem with the final part because I used the Else function! Can I present you the problem?

Comment: you'd better edit your question and update the code you're having problems with. but please consider that there's no _final part_ in my code: as long as your issue stays _"the value in the upper row should replace the value in the lower row if upper value is smaller than 1.3"_ than you'd simply have to run it as it is

Comment: :-) Just a sec, because the instructions for writting the code are in French and French can be tricky to understand, sometimes, especially when they come from someone who does not know VBA ... Just a sec ...

Comment: Yep, this is it: if in the upper cell, for example, we have 1.2 and in the coresponding cell under it we have 0.6, as 1.2 < 1.3 than 1.2 takes the place of 0.6. The problem with your code is that it puts the change in another row just under the first two and I have to replace the numbers in the same row! So 1.2 should replace 0.6 in the same cell not in another one! Thank you!

Comment: my code acts on the cells in row 61 from column "I" to "T", only if the corresponding cell in row 60 is below 1.3. If you changed it, then post what you've done

Comment: You are right, I did a mistake! It is the other way arround: if value in row 60 is > than 1.3 then that value should replace the value in row 61.

Comment: This is what I wrote:
Sub main()
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A1:D1") 
    If cell.Value > 1.3 Then Range("A2:D2").Value = Range("A1:D1").Value
Next cell

End Sub

Comment: so the change in the code is elementary: see edited answer

Comment: your code in the comment is wrong. just keep my code and just substitute "mySheet" with "Feuil1" and "I60:T60" with "A1:D1". see edited answer

Comment: I will do that! Thank you for being patient with a rookie!

Comment: you are welcome. If my answer fulfilled your original question please mark it as accepted. thank you

Comment: It gives me the "Error 9 subscript out of range" - do you think it has anything to do with the fact that Excel and everything else are in French ??? Because I used the code in the original excel file .... which is in French

Comment: in `Worksheets("Feuil1")...` in lieu of "Feuil1" you must type the actual name of the worksheet you see in its tab. VBA is language independent, but user defined names aren't...

Comment: I did that, look:
Sub main()
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Worksheets("rentabilité SAS 1").Range("I60:T60")
If cell.Value > 1.3 Then cell.Offset(1).Value = cell.Value
Next cell

End Sub

Comment: The Range in the initial excel is the one above

Comment: it must work if you have a worksheet named _"rentabilité SAS 1"_ (of course without double quotes...) in the **_same workbook where the macro resides in**_. Otherwise if your macro resides in a workbook other than that where "rentabilité SAS 1" worksheet does, then you have to fully qualify the `Range` with the `Workbook` reference too, like: `Workbooks("MyOtherWorkbok").Worksheets("rentabilité SAS 1").Range("I60:T60")`, where you have to change "MyOtherWorkbok" with the actual name of the `Workbook` where "rentabilité SAS 1" `Worksheet` resides

Comment: you are welcome. if my answer fulfilled your question please mark it as accepted. thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. You should indent you code correctly so it is easier to read.
2. Every `If` statement needs to be terminated with an `End If`
3. You can only use a `Next` statement within a `For` loop to start the next iteration

Your main problem looks like a combination of these 3 points.

Answer (score 0):

Without understand what you are trying to achieve, and what should be nested where, you need to finish each `If` with `End If`.

Also you can't jump to `Next i` inside your `For j` loop. Better off adding an error handler or something to jump outside the `For j` loop, something like the following:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


For i = 1 To 12

If Cells(60, 8 + i) < 1.3 Then
    Cells(60, 8 + i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Cells(61, 8 + i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecialext Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

    If Cells(60, 8 + i) > 1.3 Then
        For j = 1 To 10
            Cells(60, 8 + i).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Cells(61, 8 + i).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

            If Cells(60, 8 + i) < 1.3 Then
                Cells(60, 8 + i).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Cells(61, 8 + i).Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
            If Cells(60, 8 + i) = Cells(61, 8 + i) Then
                GoTo ErrHandler:
            Else
                Cells(60, 8 + i).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Cells(61, 8 + i).Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
            If Cells(60, 8 + i) < 1.3 Then
                Cells(60, 8 + i).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Cells(61, 8 + i).Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
        Next j
    End If
End If
ErrHandler
Next i

End Sub
```

The first two `If`'s are closed after the `Next j` if this is wrong (hard to tell from your code) then move them further up the code.

Comment: Try to understand it before trying it ;) And if it pushes you in the right direction feel free to upvote and/or accept!